# How to prevent chrome from opening on each run of a juypter notebook that generates a graphviz file?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, graphviz

I am running graphviz inside a jupyter notebook in vs code. Everytime I run a cell that generates a graphviz dot Windows sees the file and opens it in Chrome. It is also displayed inline in the jupyter notebook where I want it. How can I prevent Chrome from opening?

I've tried creating a launch.json as the project didn't have one. This didn't make a difference. I can't find any available configuration settings I can change to prevent Chrome opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really obvious answer. When I transitioned from running the .py file from the command line to the jupyter notebook I didn't comment out the dot.view() (a graphviz call) that displays the result graph. Jupyter will display the results without this. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

To open a jupyter notebook or jupyter lab instance without displaying it in the browser, you have to open the jupyter instance on CMD using the following command. (Of course jupyter should be on path to use jupyter commands on cmd)

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser <path>
```

and similarly for jupyter lab:

```
jupyter lab --no-browser <path>
```

The path is optional, and if you dont add a path it simply open C:\ as your default path.

Comment: I'm running jupyter notebooks in VS code, not from the command line.

Comment: I tried starting a notebook with the --no-browser flag and then connecting to that server from VS code but Chrome still opens every time I run a cell that generates a graph. Really annoying.